# browserify-shim глобально для всех зависимостей

Tags: gulp

В своей сборке я использую `gulp` + `browserify` + `browserify-shim`.
Я подключаю у себя в проекте другие библиотеки, которые находятся в папке `node_modules`. Сейчас есть такая проблема, что я и одна из библиотек используем одну и ту же зависимость - `bluebird`. Но `bluebird` я подключаю глобально, и не хочу паковать.
В `package.json` у меня есть для этого вот такое правило

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": ["browserify-shim"]
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "bluebird": "global:Promise",
}
```

Но это правило не распространяется на другие библиотеке и поэтому `bluebird` всё равно пакуется.

Сам таск выглядит стандартно

```
gulp.task('testjs', function () {
    var b = browserify({
        entries: 'app.js'
    });

    return b
        .transform(babelify, {"global":"true", "compact":"false"})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) { console.log('Error: ' + err.message); })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(rename({suffix: ".min"}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Как заставить распространить это правило глобально на любые подключаемые библиотеки и их зависимости?

В идеале хотелось бы видеть настройки как у `babelify`, ставишь `"global":"true"` и всё работает, но не нашёл такого для shim